# How to use GZipStream from PCL library?

Tags: c#, xamarin, portable-class-library

I am trying to create a PCL that needs a `System.IO.Compression.GZipStream`. My PCL shall be used on 'regular' .NET 4.x, and Xamarin.iOS.

Now both of these platforms seem to have this class: I can create a  project for each of these platforms and have access to it just fine.

However, if I create a PCL targeting *.NET Framework 4.5* and *Xamarin.iOS* (in Visual Studio 2015), the class cannot be found as it appears to be outside the PCL profile subset.

So my questions are:

- why don't have I access to compression even though it appears to be available on both platforms (e.g., this seems to indicate it is part of the .NET 4.5 PCL profile), and
- what can I do to get access?

---

**My PCL targets setup:**

[image]

**What happens if I try to deselect Silverlight 5:**

[image]

Comment: A PCL profile that **only** targets .NET 4.5 and Xamarin.iOS? Could you please post an image of your full PCL target setup?

Comment: Profile 111, which covers .NET 4.5, Windows 8, Windows Phone 8.1 (non-Silverlight) together with all Xamarin targets (iOS Unified, iOS Classic and Android) definitely supports `System.IO.Compression.GZipStream`. Try that one!

Comment: [Added an image here](https://imgur.com/e86zrld) of my settings and the code that does not have the Compression package. The other targets (except NET45 and IOS) are automatically selected since VS claims they are identical.

Comment: After you have de-selected *Silverlight 5*, select instead *Windows 8* (from the drop-down menu that right now shows *Windows Universal 10.0*) and *Windows Phone 8.1*. This will turn your PCL profile into number 111.

Comment: Yes, after I changed the profile manually (in the csproj) thats what I ended up with. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@anders is right. Your screenshot shows you have Silverlight selected in your PCL profile.

To enable Profile111 either edit your .csproj or in VS2015 check:

- .NET Framework 4.5
- ASP.NET Core 5.0
- Windows 8
- Windows Phone 8.1
- Xamarin.Android
- Xamarin.iOS
- Xamarin.iOS (Classic)

On why it is not available even though you checked compatible profiles: Support for each feature in a PCL needs to be added specifically to the PCL profiles. It does not come automatically. Not every subset of selected platforms exists as PCL profile. What happened is that you checked the platforms that you were interested it. Then Visual Studio choose one of the profiles it was compatible with. In this case unfortunately the profile that includes Silverlight. Microsoft admits this is confusing and will improve this.

Comment: Just to add - the selections shown in your screen shot indicate Profile24.  Try Profile111 as Anders described in the OP comments.  (Edit your .csproj's `TargetFrameworkProfile` setting.)

Comment: I can't set this for some reason, VS doesn't let me. Every time I de-select Silverlight I receive an `The following will be automatically targeted because they support the same set of portable APIs: Silverlight 5` ([see this image](https://imgur.com/ET5Lcf9)). Once I click OK it will be selected automatically and I'm back to square one. Why would that be?

Comment: Update: I changed to `Profile111` manually, when I now load the project I receive `This project requires a Visual Studio update to load. Right-click on the project and chose 'Download Update'`. Problem is, that then only catapults me to the Microsoft start page ...

Comment: Update 2: After more fiddling around, installing seemingly unrelated VS updates (Windows 10 SDK) and reloading the project a number of times the manual change seems to have worked.